# Format date in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following line;

```
body += "Date: " + myDateVar | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm' + ".";
```

My question is, how do i correctly format the line above, so the format actually works? I get an error, but this works fine, but just no formatting:

```
body += "Date: " + myDateVar + ".";
```

Comment: Is this in the template, or in the controller?

Comment: What are you trying to do there? Normally you would do it like this: `...>Date: {{myDateVar : date: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'}}.<...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your code is in controller.

You need to inject in the controller the $filter service, then use it like this:

```
yourFilteredDate= $filter('date')(myDateVar, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

Because you can use the pipe | only in views.